# Why SQL query doubles the result values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables that I wan't to join.  Players(table), PlayerGameStats(table) and GoaliegameStats(table). When I run my SQL query I get the values twice. I have two goalies that have data like goalsagainst and dressed(how many games). Other goalie has 2 dressed games and 8 goals against total (gameID=1 3 goals against & gameID=2 5 goals against) and other goalie has 0 games and 0 values. As a result I get 16 goals total for that "dressed" goalie.

I've tried different SQL JOINs and GROUP BY combinations. Nothing works.

```
    SELECT
        players.jersey,
        players.lastname,  
        SUM(playergamestats.dressed) AS games, 
        SUM(goaliegamestats.goalsagainst) AS ga, 
        COALESCE(SUM(goaliegamestats.goalsagainst) DIV
        SUM(playergamestats.dressed),0) AS gaperg
    FROM players 
        LEFT JOIN goaliegamestats
        ON players.playerid=goaliegamestats.playerid
        LEFT JOIN playergamestats
        ON players.playerid=playergamestats.playerid 
    WHERE players.position = 'G' 
    GROUP BY playergamestats.playerid 
    ORDER BY points DESC ;
```

I get this result:

```
    |jersey|lastname|games|ga|gaperg|
    ===============================
    |33    |Johnson |4    |16| 4   |
    |29    |Doe     |0    |0 | 0   |
```

Instead of this:

```
    |jersey|lastname|games|ga|gaperg|
    ===============================
    |33    |Johnson |2    |8 | 4   |
    |29    |Doe     |0    |0 | 0   |
```

Comment: This is because you are aggregating along two dimensions at the same time, creating a Cartesian product for each player.  You need to aggregate the secondary tables *before* joining them in.

Comment: could you share source tables structure ?

Comment: in thoery a quick fix which can work is `(SUM(<column>) / COUNT(<column>)) as alias` which should "unmultiply" which might not work in all cases (NULL values related) so you can better use a delivered table approach where you aggregate... `SELECT * FROM players LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) ...GROUP BY ...) ..`

Answer (score 1):

The double join is resulting in double counting, in this case double counting in the `goaliegamestats` table which was joined first in the query.  One workaround is to perform the aggregations in separate subqueries, and then join them:

```
SELECT
    p.jersey,
    p.lastname,  
    COALESCE(SUM(go.DIV), 0) AS DIV,
    COALESCE(SUM(pl.gaperg), 0) AS gaperg
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT playerid, SUM(goalsagainst) AS DIV
    FROM goaliegamestats
    GROUP BY playerid
) go
    ON p.playerid = go.playerid
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT playerid, SUM(dressed) AS gaperg
    FROM playergamestats
    GROUP BY playerid
) pl
    ON p.playerid = pl.playerid 
WHERE
    p.position = 'G' 
ORDER BY
    points DESC;
```

Comment: TY for quick reply!

I tried your solution and it works! Only problem is that now I can't get the stats of the goalie with no values.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    players.jersey,
    players.lastname,
    COALESCE(SUM(goaliegamestats.ga), 0) AS ga,
    COALESCE(SUM(playergamestats.games), 0) AS games,
    COALESCE(ga DIV games) AS gaperg
FROM players
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT
       playerid,
       COALESCE(SUM(goaliegamestats.goalsagainst),0) AS ga 
       FROM goaliegamestats 
       GROUP BY playerid) goaliegamestats
       ON players.playerid=goaliegamestats.playerid
    LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
       playerid,
       COALESCE(SUM(dressed),0) AS games
       FROM playergamestats
       GROUP BY playerid)
       playergamestats ON players.playerid=playergamestats.playerid
WHERE players.position = 'G' 
ORDER BY games DESC ;

//Now the result is:
|jersey|lastname|ga|games|gaperg|
=================================
|33    |Johnson |8 |2    |4     |
```

I want to see the other goalie as well.